# How to find index in a zipped list by condition of the elements of tuples (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, zip

I am new an familiarizing myself to Haskell and yet don't know how to work around problems like this:

I have a zipped (from a `Bool` and an `Int` list) list of tuples that have `(Bool, Int)` form. How can I find index of the (one) element that has values `True` as first and 'minimum of the seconds' as second? Is there any fancy library functions I can use?

Comment: What have you attempted?  There are several functions in `Data.List` that can help with this.  The first would be pretty easy with `filter`, the second would be pretty easy with `minimumBy`.

Comment: In this case, `findIndex` seems like a better match than `filter` to me. Or perhaps just `elemIndex`, assuming you've already calculated the minimum separately.

Comment: Note that indexes into a lists are often a bad idea (at least it's not efficient). Solutions based directly on sorting / filtering are generally more idiomatic. If you absolutely need indices then you should probably be using arrays / [`Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector.html)s instead of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first element is a `Bool` you can filter on it by using just `fst`:

```
filter fst l
```

In the more general case you'll have a type `a` and a predicate `p :: a -> Bool`. Then you would filter by composing `p` with `fst`:

```
filter (p . fst) l
```

Now for the second step, you want to find the minimum based on a custom criteria (as opposed to the default `compare`). That's exactly what [`minimumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v%3aminimumBy) from Data.List does. It expects a comparison function of type `(a -> a -> Ordering)`. You can write your own comparison function but there is a better way using [`on`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/libraries/base/Data-Function.html#v%3aon) from Data.Function. To find the minimum element looking at the second elements you would say:

```
minimumBy (compare `on` snd)
```

Finding the index is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your real goal here is to find the value of the minimum, and you can do that without knowing the position of the minimum.

If you need to handle the case of an empty list, then you just return a Maybe type,
since the minimum of an empty list is undefined.

Here are two possibilities: getMin, and getMin2

```
import Data.List (sortBy, foldl')

head' :: [a] -> Maybe a
head' [] = Nothing
head' (a:as) = Just a

getMin  :: [(Bool, Int)] -> Maybe (Bool, Int)
getMin  vs = head' $ sortBy (\i j -> compare (snd i) (snd j)) $ filter fst vs

getMin2 :: [(Bool, Int)] -> Maybe Int
getMin2 vs = foldl' r Nothing vs where
    r (Just i) (b,j) = case (b, compare j i) of
                          (True, LT) -> Just j
                          otherwise  -> Just i
    r Nothing (b,j)  = case b of
                          True  -> Just j
                          False -> Nothing

Data.List> getMin  [(True, 4), (False, 0), (True, 3)]
Just (True,3)
Data.List> getMin2  [(True, 4), (False, 0), (True, 3)]
Just 3
```